# How do I exclude certain districts from an R `tmap` city plot using `osmdata`?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, sf

I am trying to plot only District (quan) 1 of Ho Chi Minh city, and the wards (phuong) within it, in an aesthetically pleasing way.  Despite reading the `osmdata` vignette and help, I can't work out how to exclude the surrounding wards and districts.

(Ideally I would also like to know how to leave the external ward boundaries in, but without text labels.)

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to mapping. My code and resulting map so far is below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(extrafont)
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(tmap)



bb <- getbb('District 1, Ho Chi Minh City')



quans <- opq(bbox = bb) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = 'admin_level', value = '6') %>% 
  osmdata_sf # %>% trim_osmdata(bb)

quansPoly <- quans$osm_multipolygons
quansPoly_Q1 <- quansPoly[1,] # Manual district extraction; should be unnecessary!



phuongs <- opq(bbox = bb) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = 'admin_level', value = '8') %>% 
  osmdata_sf # %>% trim_osmdata(bb)

phuongsPoly <- phuongs$osm_multipolygons



tm_shape(quansPoly_Q1) +
  tm_borders(col = 'red', lwd = 3, alpha = 0.1) +
tm_shape(phuongsPoly) +
  tm_polygons(title = 'Municipalities', lwd = 3, border.alpha = .2, alpha = 0.1) +
    tm_text(text = "name.zh", fontfamily = "Han-Nom Kai", size = 1.2, col = "black") +
    tm_style("watercolor") +
    tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE, legend.show = T, legend.width = .2, legend.height = .2, legend.text.size = .9, legend.title.fontfamily = "Garamond Premier Pro Semibold Italic Caption", legend.position = c(.8, .1), frame.lwd = 3, bg.color = "papayawhip", frame.double.line = T, title = "HCMC, District I", fontfamily = "Garamond Premier Pro Bold Caption", title.size = 1.5, title.position = c(.03, .95)) +
  tm_shape(phuongsPoly) +
      tm_text(text = "name", fontfamily = "Garamond Premier Pro Semibold Italic Caption", size = .8, ymod = 1.1) +
  tm_shape(quansPoly_Q1) +
  tm_borders(col = 'red', lwd = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
  tm_grid(projection = 'longlat', n.x = 5) + tm_scale_bar() +
  tm_compass(position = c('right', 'top'))
```

[image: HCMC map]